# apache alias or redirect short url

Tags: apache, url, alias

I would like to have a short url like:

```
https://domain/essr
```

to evaluate to:

```
https://domain/dir1/dir2/myFile.html
```

I've been trying to use alias in my apache config but I haven't been able to make it work. How would you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using .htaccess mod-rewrite. 
Create a .htaccess file in your web root directory. And paste this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir1/dir2/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/essr/%1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Doesn't look right. When the user enters https://oiyc.org/essr I want the file at https://oiyc.org/dir1/dir2/myFile.html to be served.

Comment: When you're using this code what does it shows? Can you be more precise? thank you